# typo3 tt_guest extention error -Error in Guestbook: Extension div2007 has not been loaded

Tags: typo3

I installed typo3 `tt_guest` extension. But in the front end it shows an error

```
Error in Guestbook: Extension div2007 has not been loaded.
```

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [mentioned extension](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/div2007/), clear the cache and reload the page.